# How can I join two tables with different number of rows in Flask SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables I want to join. They possess a one-to-many relationship. One is called **FundingSource**, and the other is called **AllocationSummary**. They have a different number of columns and a different number of rows (FundingSource has more of both).

I need to query the FundingSource table (Table 1) to get all the rows from the database, and then add the rows from AllocationSummary (Table 2) to it, joining each corresponding row together and leaving the remaining AllocationSummary (Table 2) column values null since there are less rows.

The resulting table needs to have 5 of the columns from my FundingSource table (including id), 4 of the columns from my AllocationSummary table, and however many rows my FundingSource table has.

For example, this is my **FundingSource table** with 5 rows:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|     id    |  complete | department|  agency    | bill      | cfda_no   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | Y         | Dep A     | NIC        |  HR 3684  |  32.224   |
| 2         | Y         | Dep B     | AOA        |  HR 266m  |  84.225   |
| 4         | Y         | Dep C     | NSK        |  HR 3892  |  71.20    |
| 5         | N         | Dep D     | NIH        |  HR 748   |  22.865   |
| 6         | N         | Dep E     | DNS        |  HR 1319  |  93.224   |
```

This is my **AllocationSummary table** with 3 rows:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|     id    |  state    | eligible_applicant |  recipient    | amount    | 
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | NY        | State              | NIC           |  3065.0   |  
| 2         | CA        | Locality           | AOA           |  1000.0   |  
| 3         | VA        | Institution        | NSK           |  2400.0   |
```

And this is the **RESULT** table I want AFTER joining: (format was getting ruined so I attached a picture)
[Resulting Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FctFY.jpg)

Also note, I want the id column to come from the FundingSource table, so joining the two tables should not create a new table. It should query from the FundingSource table and just add on the state, eligible_applicant, recipient, and amount columns to it from the AllocationSummary table.

These are my two tables:

```
class FundingSource(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    complete = db.Column(db.String(10), default=False, nullable=False)
    department = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    agency = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    funding_source = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    bill = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    cfda_no = db.Column(db.Float(), nullable=True)
    allocations = db.relationship('AllocationSummary', backref='allocation', lazy=True) 

class AllocationSummary(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    state = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    eligible_applicant = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    recipient = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    amount = db.Column(db.Float(), nullable=False)
    funding_source_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('funding_source.id'), nullable=False)
```

Here is my .py file:

```
@main.route("/")
@main.route("/guidance_master")
def g_master():
    f_sources = FundingSource.query.all()
    return render_template('guidance_master.html', title='Guidance Master', fsources=f_sources)

@main.route("/allocationSummary")
def alloc_summ():
    all_data2 = AllocationSummary.query.join(FundingSource).filter(AllocationSummary.funding_source_id == FundingSource.id).all()
    return render_template('allocationSummary.html', title='Allocation Summary', allocs=all_data2)
```

Here is my HTML file:

```
                    ....
                    <tbody>

                    {% for row in allocs%}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.complete }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.agency }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.funding_source }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.bill }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.state }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.eligible_applicant }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.recipient }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.amount }}</td>
                    </tr>

                    {% endfor %}

                    </tbody>
                    ....
```

I just can't seem to find a way to query using attributes from 2 different tables at once to display in my table. These are some of the queries I have tried:

```
all_data2 = AllocationSummary.query.join(FundingSource).filter(AllocationSummary.funding_source_id == FundingSource.id).all()

all_data2 = db.session.query(FundingSource).outerjoin(AllocationSummary).all()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is 'id' the common field in this two table that needs to be joined on?

Comment: Yes, it's the common field in both, the primary key for each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a left outer join between `FundingSource` and `AllocationSummary`, which you can do like this:

```py
rows = (
    db.session.query(
        FundingSource.id,
        FundingSource.complete,
        FundingSource.department,
        FundingSource.agency,
        FundingSource.bill,
        FundingSource.cfda_no,
        AllocationSummary.state,
        AllocationSummary.eligible_applicant,
        AllocationSummary.recipient,
        AllocationSummary.amount,
    )
    .join(
        AllocationSummary,
        FundingSource.id == AllocationSummary.funding_source_id,
        isouter=True,
    )
    .all()
)
```

The above is a bit cumbersome, but allows the HTML template to be a simple loop.  The converse - simple Python but complicated template - could be achieved by passing `FundingSource.query.all()` to the template and handle multiple or missing allocations there.

Comment: You are AMAAZING! No one has been able to give me the right answer. Tysm!!

Answer (score -1):

You can do this is a few ways

**1. Pandas merge**

```
FundingSource_AllocationSummary = FundingSource.merge(AllocationSummary, how='left', on='id')
```

**2. SQL Alchemy**

```
import sqlalchemy
from pandasql import sqldf

FundingSource_AllocationSummary = sqldf('SELECT f.*, a.state, a.eligible_applicant, a.recipient, a.amount
FROM FundingSource as f
LEFT JOIN AllocationSummary as a
ON f.id = a.id')
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for responding. Pycharm is not accepting this SQL dialect from #2 because it needs to be in SQLAlchemy representation, and how would you query this? I also re-uploaded the result I am looking for in my post above because the link wasn't working before. If you could please check that too

Comment: I changed my SQL dialect for #2, but when I run it, I get this error: AttributeError: type object 'FundingSource' has no attribute 'index'. But where is index coming from?